# how does google analytics know screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

How can they get the user's OS settings?

Obviously they don't check the window size, that is not what resulotion is.

Comment: It's not that bad. At least no one said LMGTFY.

Comment: @vsync: You *can* delete it. There's a button below your post.

Comment: @Bergi - no i can't..SO doesn't work that way..

Comment: @vsync: I see, it's only [too late](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/183280) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They use the [`window.screen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.screen) object to find out the dimensions of the screen.

Comment: I've noticed that `window.screen` doesn't report the real screen resolution if the browser is in `zoom` mode

Comment: @vsync: Yes, you are right. This varies between browsers. Chrome reports the pixel size of the screen regardless of zoom, but IE and Firefox seems to report the size in "browser pixels", i.e. how many pixels displayed at that zoom level that would fill the screen.

Comment: so how can one detect the real screen resolution is user is zoomed?